# What is the difference between .NET Core and .NET Standard Class Library project types?

Tags: .net, .net-core, class-library, .net-standard

In Visual Studio, there are at least three different types of class libraries you can create:

- Class Library (.NET Framework)
- Class Library (.NET Standard)
- Class Library (.NET Core)

While the first is what we've been using for years, a major point of confusion I've been having is when to use the .NET Standard and .NET Core class library types. I've been bitten by this recently when attempting to [multi-target different framework versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42748869/983064), and [creating a unit test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938879/cant-get-xunit-tests-to-run-with-net-core).

So, what is the difference between *Class Library (.NET Standard)* and *Class Library (.NET Core)*, why do both exist, and when should we use one over the other?

Comment: You missed one: Class Library (Portable).  Core == framework, .NET Standard == portable.

Comment: There was one from Xamarin too, but these other ones don't add any value to the question :)

Comment: Well, they do.  The core idea is the they gave up on the portable approach, it suffered too heavily from the n! problem with *way* too many profiles.  So now you've got 7 standards to choose from.  Most are not actually portable right now :)  .NETCore is not done by a long shot, probably takes another two years at the clip they are going.

Comment: OP said "at least 3 different types". The post was accurate.

Comment: and also there is Universal Windows

Comment: I was confused by the naming of Core which is not a core subset of neither the Standard nor the Framework plateform.
Also we regularly see ASP associated with .Net Core. This is also very confusing...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks

Comment: [Helpful discussion on MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7035edc6-97fc-49ee-8eee-2fa4d040a63b/what-are-differences-between-net-framwork-net-standard-and-net-core)

Comment: now you have .net 5. it is where the .net framework and .net core met each other.

Comment: In short , a use case would be ,  if you want a library to support both .Net Framework and .Net Core. Then you should use .NET Std.  Then both applications can use this library.

Comment: @HansPassant what specifically are you referring to here as the n! problem?

Answer (score 774, accepted):

> When should we use one over the other?

The decision is a trade-off between compatibility and API access.

Use a .NET Standard library when you want to increase the number of applications that will be compatible with your library, and you are okay with a decrease in the .NET API surface area your library can access.

Use a .NET Core library when you want to increase the .NET API surface area your library can access, and you are okay with allowing only .NET Core applications to be compatible with your library.

For example, a library that targets .NET Standard 1.3 [will be compatible with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#net-platforms-support) applications that target .NET Framework 4.6, .NET Core 1.0, Universal Windows Platform 10.0, and any other platform that supports .NET Standard 1.3. The library will not have access to some parts of the .NET API, though. For instance, the  [`Microsoft.NETCore.CoreCLR`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR/) package is compatible with .NET Core, but not with .NET Standard.

> What is the difference between Class Library (.NET Standard) and Class Library (.NET Core)?

Compatibility: Libraries that target .NET Standard will run on any .NET Standard compliant runtime, such as .NET Core, .NET Framework, [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29)/[Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin). On the other hand, libraries that target .NET Core can only run on the .NET Core runtime.

API Surface Area: .NET Standard libraries come with everything in `NETStandard.Library`, whereas .NET Core libraries come with everything in `Microsoft.NETCore.App`. The latter includes approximately 20 additional libraries, some of which we can add manually to our .NET Standard library (such as `System.Threading.Thread`) and some of which are not compatible with the .NET Standard (such as `Microsoft.NETCore.CoreCLR`).

Also, .NET Core libraries specify a runtime and come with an application model. That's important, for instance, to make unit test class libraries runnable.

> Why do both exist?

Ignoring libraries for a moment, the reason that .NET Standard exists is for portability; it defines a set of APIs that .NET platforms agree to implement. Any platform that implements a .NET Standard is compatible with libraries that target that .NET Standard. One of those compatible platforms is .NET Core.

Coming back to libraries, the .NET Standard library templates exist to run on multiple runtimes (at the expense of API surface area). Conversely, the .NET Core library templates exist to access more API surface area (at the expense of compatibility) and to specify a platform against which to build an executable.

[Here is an interactive matrix](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard#versions) that shows which .NET Standard supports which .NET implementation(s) and how much API surface area is available.

Comment: Very good answer. An additional question though (relates to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938879/cant-get-xunit-tests-to-run-with-net-core/42942592#42942592): why is an application model necessary to run unit tests? This was never the case in the past, when we used non-runnable class libraries to hold collections of unit tests.

Comment: I've updated my answer to the linked question. TL;DR; In the past, class libraries targeted the full framework, which includes an application model.

Comment: You forgot to cover Class Library (.NET Framework), is it compatible with .NET Standard and .NET Core?

Comment: @Tomas, As .net standard can be understood as an interface rather than a library, then any library built against a specific version of .net standard can be referenced by either .net framework, or .net core, or other .net variant that implements that specific version of .net standard. So a .net framework or a .net core library is "compatible" with any .net standard library, provided that library is build against a version of .net standard that the .net framework or .net core libraries implement. .net framework and .net core are not compatible with each other. they target different runtimes.

Comment: [This diagram](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/981310) really helped me get it.

Comment: It´s not what Microsoft says at MSDN! Standard "it´s a formal use.."

Comment: Can you give me more details, @BerBar, about what you mean? I'd like to understand your concern better.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin please see my anwser. Don't forget to mention in your anwser about the .NET CORE cross-plataform stuff the main point of . NET CORE framework.

Comment: @BerBar The original question was about the difference between .NET Standard and .NET Core. That's why I omitted cross-platform details, because cross-platform is not a difference between Core and Standard. I've intentionally kept my answer scoped to the original question.

Comment: Excellent write up! This is very helpful +1

Answer (score 457):

A **.NET Core Class Library** is built upon the **.NET Standard**. If you want to implement a library that is portable to the **.NET Framework**, **.NET Core** and **[Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin)**, choose a **.NET Standard Library**

**.NET Core will ultimately implement .NET Standard 2** (as will **Xamarin** and **.NET Framework**)

**.NET Core**, **Xamarin** and **.NET Framework** can, therefore, be identified as **flavours** of **.NET Standard**

To future-proof your applications for code sharing and reuse, you would rather implement .NET Standard libraries.

Microsoft also recommends that you use **.NET Standard** instead of **Portable Class Libraries**.

To quote MSDN as an authoritative source, **.NET Standard** is intended to be **One Library to Rule Them All**. As pictures are worth a thousand words, the following will make things very clear:

**1. Your current application scenario (fragmented)**

Like most of us, you are probably in the situation below:
(.NET Framework, Xamarin and now .NET Core flavoured applications)

[image]

**2. What the .NET Standard Library will enable for you (cross-framework compatibility)**

Implementing a .NET Standard Library allows code sharing across all these different flavours:

[image: One Library to Rule them All]

For the impatient:

1. **.NET Standard** solves the code sharing problem for .NET developers across all platforms by bringing all the APIs that you expect and love across the environments that you need: desktop applications, mobile apps & games, and cloud services:
2. **.NET Standard** is a **set of APIs** that **all** .NET platforms **have to implement**. This **unifies the .NET platforms** and **prevents future fragmentation**.
3. **.NET Standard 2.0** will be implemented by **.NET Framework**, .**NET Core**,
   and **Xamarin**. For **.NET Core**, this will add many of the existing APIs
   that have been requested.
4. **.NET Standard 2.0** includes a compatibility shim for **.NET Framework** binaries, significantly increasing the set of libraries that you can reference from your .NET Standard libraries.
5. **.NET Standard** **will replace Portable Class Libraries (PCLs)** as the
   tooling story for building multi-platform .NET libraries.

For a table to help understand what the highest version of .NET Standard that you can target, based on which .NET platforms you intend to run on, [head over here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md).

Sources: [MSDN: Introducing .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a little misplaced in that graphic, as it can be used with the full .NET Framework, not only .NET Core, because it actually targets .NET Standard.

Comment: @Neme, I don't think you understand ...It isn't misplaced at all. That diagram illustrates how each library-type/.Net flavour relates to the other and where it fits in the overall frame of things. It gives a hierarchical idea of the scope that each library has from generic to specific...

Comment: But you can create an ASP.NET Core app with the full .NET Framework - ASP.NET Core really belongs to the same layer as .NET Standard does. It's not constrained to just .NET Core.

Comment: @Neme Firstly, yes .Net Core can include .Net Framework libraries but losing cross-platform reuse(only for Windows - not *nix or OSX, or reuse in Xamarin). A situation which was catered for given that many have & want to reuse existing  libraries written  thein full.Net Framework with no interest for cross-platform benefits (OS-level and App-Model level)...If you still feel I'm wrong, perhaps you can argue with Microsoft, who authored those images... :-)

Comment: I'm not talking about combining .NET Core & .NET Framework. My point is that ASP.NET Core isn't dependent on .NET Core at all, despite the name. It is written as a library that targets .NET Standard, therefore you can use it everywhere you can use .NET Standard. Yes, they made a mistake in that image.

Comment: You can see it here: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/03/new-project.png

Comment: So if what I want to a cross-platform application, I can simply choose .Net Core. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @OgrishMan, if you want **a common library/code** that **can be referenced** by .Net Core, .Net Framework, Xamarin or a .Net Standard library, you would **implement it in .Net Standard**

Comment: @OgrishMan **You cannot create an executable in .Net Standard**. It can only be a Class Library, that can be referenced by other executing code. **It has no runtime**.

Comment: Plagiarised (wholesale) at Quora, [Ankusha Rana's answer *"What is the difference between .NET Standard and .NET Core?"*](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-NET-Standard-and-NET-Core/answer/Ankusha-Rana)

Comment: Interesting @PeterMortensen... I guess if he/she is sharing and it is helpful to more people, it's a good thing.:) Thanks for the edits, by the way

Answer (score 105):

The short answer would be:

```
IAnimal == .NetStandard (General)
ICat == .NetCore (Less general)
IDog == .NetFramework (Specific / oldest and has the most features)
```

Comment: Why this answer is not marked a good answer ? Simple and clean.

Comment: @Joe.wang as I see it is bad that it messes the relationship between .NET Core and .NET Framework. If .NET Core is the bird, then .NET Framework cannot be the eagle (maybe cat is more suitable).

Comment: @LexLi is right, this muddies the waters. .NET Framework is not a subtype of .NET Core.

Comment: It's wrong,  .net core isn't compatible with .net framework

Comment: this may look bit fancy but not acurate

Comment: The original comment by @Joe sounded more accurate. edited answer by Community made it confusing

Comment: I agree this answer is nice and simple, but it does not illustrate the relationship between the standards accurately.

Comment: I agree with @Nandun, the Community edit makes the metaphor less accurate. I intrinsically knew what was meant in the original post but after this edit it now looks incorrect to me. The original way may not have been perfect but it worked as a quick and funny way to describe it.

Comment: Dogs have more features than cats? Nop :)

Comment: This comment confused me more and I started searching on whether dogs belong to cats family!

Comment: The number of edits this has suffered by various different people that changed the author's original intent outlines for me that this is an unsuitable metaphor and should be deleted, so it's a -1 from me

Comment: Hehe; this is funny

Answer (score 79):

**.NET** and **.NET Core** are two different implementations of the .NET runtime. Both Core and Framework (but especially Framework) have different profiles that include larger or smaller (or just plain different) selections of the many APIs and assemblies Microsoft has created for .NET, depending on where they are installed and in what profile.

For example, there are some different APIs available in Universal Windows apps than in the "normal" Windows profile. Even on Windows, you might have the "Client" profile vs. the "Full" profile. Additionally, there are other implementations (like [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29)) that have their own sets of libraries.

**.NET Standard** is a specification for which sets of API libraries and assemblies must be available. An app written for .NET Standard 1.0 should be able to compile and run with any version of Framework, Core, Mono, etc., that publishes support for the .NET Standard 1.0 collection of libraries. Similar is true for .NET Standard 1.1, 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, etc. As long as the runtime provides support for the version of Standard targeted by your program, your program should run there.

A project targeted at a version of Standard will not be able to make use of features that are not included in that revision of the standard. This doesn't mean you can't take dependencies on other assemblies, or APIs published by other vendors (i.e.: items on NuGet). But it does mean that any dependencies you take must also include support for your version of .NET Standard. .NET Standard is evolving quickly, but it's still new enough, and cares enough about some of the smaller runtime profiles, that this limitation can feel stifling. *(Note a year and a half later: this is starting to change, and recent .NET Standard versions are much nicer and more full-featured).*

On the other hand, an app targeted at Standard *should* be able to be used in more deployment situations, since in theory it can run with Core, Framework, Mono, etc. For a class library project looking for wide distribution, that's an attractive promise. For an end-user-focused project intended mainly for an internal audience, it may not be as much of a concern.

.NET Standard can also be useful in situations where the system administrator team is wanting to move from ASP.NET on Windows to ASP.NET for .NET Core on Linux for philosophical or cost reasons, but the Development team wants to continue working against .NET Framework in Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: While a good overview of what .NET Core and .NET Standard are, this answer fails to answer the question about class libraries targeting each of these.

Comment: If that's your goal, the question needs to be closed as either "unclear what you're asking", since there are always going to be too many situational specifics that play into a given person's environment for us to ever just tell you what to do, or as "Too Broad" if you're asking about the general case. All we can do here is give you info about the products, so you can be informed for making your own decision.

Comment: That is clearly not the case, as another has accurately answered the question. My question was about the class libraries. Your answer was about the frameworks.

Answer (score 38):

.NET Framework and .NET Core are both frameworks.

.NET Standard is a standard (in other words, a specification).

You can make an executable project (like a console application, or ASP.NET application) with .NET Framework and .NET Core, but not with .NET Standard.

With .NET Standard you can make only a class library project that cannot be executed standalone and should be referenced by another .NET Core or .NET Framework executable project.

Answer (score 31):

*I hope this will help to understand the **relationship between .NET Standard API surface and other .NET platforms**. Each interface represents a target framework and methods represents groups of APIs available on that target framework.*

```
namespace Analogy
{
    // .NET Standard

    interface INetStandard10
    {
        void Primitives();
        void Reflection();
        void Tasks();
        void Xml();
        void Collections();
        void Linq();
    }

    interface INetStandard11 : INetStandard10
    {
        void ConcurrentCollections();
        void LinqParallel();
        void Compression();
        void HttpClient();
    }

    interface INetStandard12 : INetStandard11
    {
        void ThreadingTimer();
    }

    interface INetStandard13 : INetStandard12
    {
        //.NET Standard 1.3 specific APIs
    }

    // And so on ...


    // .NET Framework

    interface INetFramework45 : INetStandard11
    {
        void FileSystem();
        void Console();
        void ThreadPool();
        void Crypto();
        void WebSockets();
        void Process();
        void Drawing();
        void SystemWeb();
        void WPF();
        void WindowsForms();
        void WCF();
    }

    interface INetFramework451 : INetFramework45, INetStandard12
    {
        // .NET Framework 4.5.1 specific APIs
    }

    interface INetFramework452 : INetFramework451, INetStandard12
    {
        // .NET Framework 4.5.2 specific APIs
    }

    interface INetFramework46 : INetFramework452, INetStandard13
    {
        // .NET Framework 4.6 specific APIs
    }

    interface INetFramework461 : INetFramework46, INetStandard14
    {
        // .NET Framework 4.6.1 specific APIs
    }

    interface INetFramework462 : INetFramework461, INetStandard15
    {
        // .NET Framework 4.6.2 specific APIs
    }

    // .NET Core
    interface INetCoreApp10 : INetStandard15
    {
        // TODO: .NET Core 1.0 specific APIs
    }
    // Windows Universal Platform
    interface IWindowsUniversalPlatform : INetStandard13
    {
        void GPS();
        void Xaml();
    }

    // Xamarin
    interface IXamarinIOS : INetStandard15
    {
        void AppleAPIs();
    }

    interface IXamarinAndroid : INetStandard15
    {
        void GoogleAPIs();
    }
    // Future platform

    interface ISomeFuturePlatform : INetStandard13
    {
        // A future platform chooses to implement a specific .NET Standard version.
        // All libraries that target that version are instantly compatible with this new
        // platform
    }

}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/8939f305567e1755412d6dc0b8baf1b7)

Answer (score 27):

Another way of explaining the difference could be with real world examples, as most of us mere mortals will use existing tools and frameworks ([Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin), [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)), etc.) to do the job.

So, with .NET Framework you have all the .NET tools to work with, but you can only target Windows applications ([UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform), [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), etc.). Since .NET Framework is closed source there isn't much to do about it.

With .NET Core you have fewer tools, but you can target the main *desktop platforms* (Windows, Linux, and Mac). This is specially useful in ASP.NET Core applications, since you can now host ASP.NET on Linux (cheaper hosting prices). Now, since .NET Core was open sourced, it's technically possible to develop libraries for other platforms. But since there aren't frameworks that support it, I don't think that's a good idea.

With .NET Standard you have even fewer tools, but you can target all/most platforms. You can target *mobile* thanks to Xamarin, and you can even target *game consoles* thanks to Mono/Unity. It's also possible to target web clients with the UNO platform and [Blazor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazor) (although both are kind of experimental right now).

In a real-world application you may need to use all of them. For example, I developed a [point of sale](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/point_of_sale#Noun) application that had the following architecture:

**Shared both server and slient:**

- A .NET Standard library that handles the *models* of my application.
- A .NET Standard library that handles the validation of data sent by the clients.

Since it's a .NET Standard library, it can be used in any other project (client and server).

Also a nice advantage of having the validation on a .NET standard library since I can be sure the same validation is applied on the server and the client. Server is mandatory, while client is optional and useful to reduce traffic.

**Server side (Web API):**

- A .NET Standard (could be .NET Core as well) library that handles all the database connections.
- A .NET Core project that handles the Rest API and makes use of the
  database library.

As this is developed in .NET Core, I can host the application on a Linux server.

**Client side ([MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) with [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) + Xamarin.Forms Android/iOS):**

- A .NET Standard library that handles the client API connection.
- A .NET Standard library that handles the *ViewModels logic*. It is used in
  all the views.
- A .NET Framework WPF application that handles the WPF views for a
  windows application. WPF applications can be .NET core now, although they only work on Windows currently. AvaloniaUI is a good alternative for making *desktop* GUI applications for other desktop platforms.
- A .NET Standard library that handles Xamarin forms views.
- A Xamarin Android and Xamarin [iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) project.

So you can see that there's a big advantage here on the client side of the application, since I can reuse both .NET Standard libraries (*client* API and ViewModels) and just make views with no logic for the WPF, Xamarin and iOS applications.

Comment: I think this is a better answer since it incorporates the real-world.

Answer (score 12):

.NET Standard: Think of it as a big standard library. When using this as a dependency you can only make libraries (.DLLs), not executables. A library made with .NET standard as a dependency can be added to a Xamarin.Android, a Xamarin.iOS, a .NET Core Windows/OS X/Linux project.

.NET Core: Think of it as the continuation of the old .NET framework, just it's opensource and some stuff is not yet implemented and others got deprecated. It extends the .NET standard with extra functions, but it only runs on *desktops*. When adding this as a dependency you can make runnable applications on Windows, Linux and OS X. (Although console only for now, no GUIs). So .NET Core = .NET Standard + desktop specific stuff.

Also [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) uses it and the new [ASP.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core) uses it as a dependency too.

Answer (score 9):

.NET Standard exists mainly to improve code sharing and make the APIs available in each .NET implementation more consistent.

While creating libraries we can have the target as .NET Standard 2.0 so that the library created would be compatible with different versions of .NET Framework including .NET Core, [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29), etc.

Answer (score 3):

**.NET Core**
[.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/) is a free, cross-platform, open source implementation of the managed framework. It supports four types of applications: console, ASP.NET Core, cloud, and Universal Windows Platform (UWP). Windows Forms and Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF) are not part of .NET Core.

Technically, .NET Core only supports console applications. ASP.NET Core and UWP are application models built on top of .NET Core.

Unlike the .NET Framework, .NET Core is not considered a Windows component. Therefore, updates come as NuGet packages, not through Windows Update. Since the .NET Core runtime is installed App-Local, and applications are updated through the package manager, applications can be associated with a particular .NET Core version and be updated individually.

**.NET Standard**
Each implementation of the managed framework has its own set of Base Class Libraries. The Base Class Library (BCL) contains classes such as exception handling, strings, XML, I/O, networking, and collections.

[.NET Standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-standard/) is a specification for implementing the BCL. Since a .NET implementation is required to follow this standard, application developers will not have to worry about different versions of the BCL for each managed framework implementation.

Framework Class Libraries (FCL) such as WPF, WCF, and ASP.NET are not part of the BCL, and therefore are not included in .NET Standard.

The relationship between .NET Standard and a .NET implementation is the same as between the HTML specification and a browser. The second is an implementation of the first.

Hence, the .NET Framework, Xamarin, and .NET Core each implement .NET Standard for the BCL in their managed framework. Since the computer industry will continue to introduce new hardware and operating systems, there will be new managed frameworks for .NET. This standard allows application developers to know that there will be a consistent set of APIs that they can rely on.

Each .NET version has an associated version of the .NET Standard.

By providing consistent APIs, porting applications to different managed implementations, as well as providing tooling, is easier.

.NET Standard is defined as a single NuGet package because all .NET implementations are required to support it. Tooling becomes easier because the tools have a consistent set of APIs to use for a given version. You can also build a single library project for multiple .NET implementations.

You can also build .NET Standard wrappers for platform specific APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers may describe the best understanding about the difference between .NET Core, .NET Standard and .NET Framework, so I just want to share my experience when choosing this over that.

In the project that you need to mix between .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET Standard. For example, at the time we build the system with .NET Core 1.0, there is no support for Window Services hosting with .NET Core.

The next reason is we were using Active Report which doesn't support .NET Core.

So we want to build an infrastructure library that can be used for both .NET Core (ASP.NET Core) and Windows Service and Reporting (.NET Framework) -> That's why we chose .NET Standard for this kind of library.
Choosing .NET standard means you need to carefully consider every class in the library should be simple and cross .NET (Core, Framework, and Standard).

**Conclusion:**

- .NET Standard for the infrastructure library and shared common. This library can be referenced by .NET Framework and .NET Core.
- .NET Framework for unsupported technologies like Active Report, Window Services (now with .NET 3.0 it supports).
- .NET Core for ASP.NET Core of course.

Microsoft just announced .NET 5: *[Introducing .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/)*

Comment: @Gigi Please read my answer carefully, I said it was when .NET Core in a 1.0 version and this case we want to design a solution to combine both .NET core and .NET framework. The ASP.NET Core support .NET Framework from 2.0 above. My answer is a story when you have to deal with multiple version of .NET. So I can't understand why you have a downvote when you don't understand the situation correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I did read your answer, and I did read the part where you referred to .NET Core 1.0. Yet I did not take that as a prerequisite to interpreting your conclusions, which would otherwise mislead people reading with the current versioning. Additionally, it seems like my comment was nuked by the Stack Overflow police, which is a shame that I've grown accustomed to on this site.

Answer (score 0):

#### .NET Framework

[Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), ASP.NET and WPF application must be developed using .NET Framework library.

#### .NET Standard

Xamarin, iOS and Mac OS X application must be developed using .NET Standard library

#### .NET Core

[Universal Windows Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) (UWP) and Linux application must be developed using .NET Core library.
The API is implemented in C++ and you can using the C++, VB.NET, C#, F# and JavaScript languages.NET

Answer (score -1):

**Every Framework has its class library.**

- Base Class Library for .Net Framework.
- Core Library for .Net core.
- Mono Class Library for Xamarin.

Microsoft has decided to bring all these class libraries to a single library that is implementable in all frameworks. For this purpose, they developed .Net standard.

Microsoft has decided to make a unified Framework. .Net 5 is a unified framework of .Net core and .Net Framework. In .Net 6, they merge Xamarin under the .Net MAUI project with .Net as well.

.Net Framework, .Net Core, Xamarin are unified to a single Framework .Net 6, so don't need to .Net standard. The goal of the .Net standard was to have a library that works in all frameworks. Now all frameworks are merged in .Net 6.

Answer (score -1):

**.NET Framework and .NET Core**

1-The .NET Framework and .NET Core are implementations of .NET

2-Both frameworks have runtime which manages the execution of applications

3-The base class library is also a part of both frameworks

4-We can create different types of projects in either framework

**.NET Standard**

1-The .NET Standard is a specification and not a .NET implementation

2-It specifies a set of APIs that all the .NET implementations have to implement

3-We can create only class library type projects with it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

.NET Core and .NET Standard are both important components of the .NET ecosystem, and they serve different purposes. Let's clarify the difference between .NET Core and .NET Standard Class Library project types:

**1. .NET Core Class Library Project:**

.NET Core is a framework for building cross-platform applications, which includes libraries, console applications, ASP.NET Core applications, etc.
A .NET Core Class Library project is specifically designed to target the .NET Core runtime. It produces libraries that are compatible with and can be used by .NET Core applications.
If you're building applications that will run on .NET Core, you would typically create a .NET Core Class Library project to share code between different parts of your application.
.NET Core has a broader scope and can be used for building various types of applications.

**2. .NET Standard Class Library Project:**

.NET Standard is a specification or set of APIs that are common across different .NET platforms, including .NET Core, .NET Framework, and Xamarin.
A .NET Standard Class Library project targets the .NET Standard, meaning it can be consumed by any .NET platform that supports that specific version of the .NET Standard.
The main purpose of .NET Standard libraries is to ensure portability and reusability of code across different .NET implementations. It's a way to create libraries that work on multiple platforms.
.NET Standard is more focused on compatibility and providing a common set of APIs.
In summary, the key difference is in their target platforms and goals:

A .NET Core Class Library targets the .NET Core platform and is used when building applications specifically for .NET Core.
A .NET Standard Class Library targets the .NET Standard, allowing code to be shared and reused across different .NET platforms, such as .NET Core, .NET Framework, and Xamarin.

Your choice between them depends on whether you want to create platform-specific libraries (for .NET Core) or libraries that work across multiple .NET platforms (using .NET Standard).