# .Net Framework dependencies in .Net Core 1.1 project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017.  Have created a .Net Core Web Application project.  I'm trying to add a .Net Framework 4.5 dependency and get the following:

```
Package X.Y.Z 1.2.0-pre-000394 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package X.Y.Z 1.2.0-pre-000394 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 supports:
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
```

I'm confused as to whether this is really possible or not using VS 2017 and .Net Core 1.1.1.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: The main issue was that I had selected the wrong project template.  I used the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) template when I should have used the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) template.  I needed the latter since I need to interact with .NET Framework dependencies in a windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

Check what framework(s) the package is targeting, and check what framework your project is targeting. As you'll see from my recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939454/what-is-the-difference-between-net-core-and-net-standard-class-library-project), there is a lot of confusion between the various frameworks and what project types to use in what circumstances.

The first package (`X.Y.Z`) seems to be targeting the full framework, although it's not clear since there doesn't seem to be a proper version (`.NETFramework,Version=v0.0`).

`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` is pretty clearly built for the full .NET Framework 4.5, and you can't use it from a .NET Core app. The answers to the question I linked above explain why; portable libraries need to target .NET Standard if they are to be used across different types of framework runtimes (e.g. .NET Framework, .NET Core, Mono). Something built for a specific framework will not automatically port over to the others.

Refer to [this chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#net-platforms-support) for info about compatibility.