# Targeting .NET Core vs .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

We've a server side "classic" WCF .NET application running on Windows. We added last year Linux support using Mono and a Web-Api replacement of WCF.
Checking the compatibility with the Api-Port tool, we found that the we would need much few changes targeting directly .NET Core instead of .NET Standard.

So for server side application like ours, that will be running only on Windows and Linux, is it correct to say that does not make any sense to target .NET Standard?

Comment: Are you sure? There are very few APIs that are supported in .Net Core 1.x/2.0, but not in .Net Standard 1.x/2.0 and most of them are not compatibility APIs. Could you list some of the APIs you're talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For server-side applications targeting .NET Core is enough.

There is a detailed answer here: [What is the difference between .NET Core and .NET Standard Class Library project types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939454/what-is-the-difference-between-net-core-and-net-standard-class-library-project)

Comment: OK thanks it makes sense. Now (yes it might be another question...) now when I create a .NET core 2.0 library (VS2017 Preview 2.1) when I see the project target, it says ".NET Standard 2.0) and I cannot choose .NET Core

Comment: .NET Standard is used for class libraries which can be used by .NET Framework and .NET Core while .NET Core 2.0 is used for applications

Comment: I mean that if a library is known to be used by .NET Core apps, it is perfectly fine to build the library targeting .NET Core only.