# Which type of Class Library project should I use for .NET Core + Xamarin Android App?

Tags: c#, android, .net, asp.net-core

I am planning to build a Mobile app in Xamarin Android & it's API in ASP.NET Core. Now I will also create few Class Library projects for Services, Repository & DTOs.

Now, there are two types of Class Library projects.

- .NET Core
- .NET Standard

Now, My question is that, which project will be supported by Xamarin Android app?
If it is .NET Standard Class Library, then will it work with .NET Core Web API Project?

Comment: this may help u https://stackoverflow.com/a/42940138/9020340

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between .NET Core and .NET Standard Class Library project types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939454/what-is-the-difference-between-net-core-and-net-standard-class-library-project)

Answer (score 0):

I think .NET Standard would be a good choice if the library is going to be used for mobile app and/or other types of app.