# Dapper Compatibility .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper

Release notes say that Dapper is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0. Why does it work with .Net Core 3.1? Since what release does it work?

Comment: You need to read up on what [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between .NET Core and .NET Standard Class Library project types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939454/what-is-the-difference-between-net-core-and-net-standard-class-library-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - I understand. .Net Standard 2.0 asks for a minimum version (.Net core 2.0). 3.1 is therefore compatible.

Thanx DavidG!

Comment: Yup; .NET Core 3.1 implements .NET Standard 2.1, which is a superset of .NET Standard 2.0, so: it all works fine