# Can Delphi call a function from a .NET Standard class library?

Tags: delphi, dllimport, .net-standard

Calling functions contained in a .NET Framework class library from Delphi has been solved long ago.

But we now have .NET Core and .NET Standard class libraries and would like know if using these in a Delphi project can be done. I'm not sure where to start or whether it is worth it. Obviously I can rebuild this library for .NET Framework but do I HAVE to do it this way?

Comment: For the miasma of confusion about .NET Core and why you may or may not want or need to use it : [What is the difference between .NET Core and .NET Standard Class Library project types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42939454/327083).  With that out of the way, what remains is the question of can you import methods from libraries built upon those frameworks - yes, because they will still be COM dlls.

Comment: In fact, it's even easier.  [MSDN : Exposing .NET Core components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com)

Comment: Does this repo show what you need? https://github.com/sauter-direkt/Delphi-CSharp-Zero

Comment: Did you try to import the .NET core COM object to Delphi? Note that you would need a Win64 Delphi application, since .NET core only supports it IIRC.