# How can I use existing .net framework 4.8 class library in .NET 6 project?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

We have .NET 6 Blazor Server-side project in Visual Studio 2022. We would like to use .Net Framework 4.8 class library in .NET 6. In this class library, we are using System.Windows.Form and we cannot recompile the class library with .NET Standard 2.0.

I have added .Net Framework 4.8 class library project as dependency for Blazor Application. I am able to compile the solution but when try to run the Blazor Application then it complaints with "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.".

We would just like to run Blazor project in windows only.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: .NET 6 and .NET Framework 4.8 are no interoperable. You will have to migrate and recompile the 4.8 library to either .NET 6 or .NET Standard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add a reference to a .NET Framework DLL from a .NET 6 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005465/can-i-add-a-reference-to-a-net-framework-dll-from-a-net-6-project)

Comment: Contrary to the comments and to my surprise, I can create a new core app inside my old solution, and access my old .net framework libraries in that same solution... So I am accessing my 4.8 libraries from a .NET 6 console app...

Comment: Same here, same surprise. I created a .NET 7 webapi project, reference a framework 4.8 project. Just works... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @LDW Did you ever find out more about the topic? I'm generally also saying that NET targetting NET Framework shouldn't work, but we have one construct, where this is done. Is it probably just a check from Microsoft in Visual Studio, which is missing?

Comment: No, I’d love to know more and why it works when the general consensus is that it shouldn’t work… I have only tried this for testing purposes, not for anything in production. Maybe @JoepGeevers knows more? It’s certainly one of my more “mysterious” .net experiences…

Comment: I was trying to solve the same issue, but I also always received FileNotFoundExceptions for referenced .Net48 assemblies.
However I found out that when I explicitely loaded the .Net48 assembly via Assembly.LoadFrom(..) it was working.
I now use the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event and load in the handler manually these Assemblies via Assembly.LoadFrom()

Answer (score -1):

You can target newer .NET versions with inclusion of Windows forms.

See the official guidance

- [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)
- [How to upgrade a Windows Forms desktop app to .NET 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-8.0)