# Use .Net framework 4.7.2 in .net 6 application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to find out if it is possible to use a .Net Framework 4.7.2 assembly in another .Net 6 libraries or .Net 6 application. I tried this with some sample projects, and at least I could add a reference to a .NET 4.7.2 in .NET 6 library or application. But based on some posts at Stack Overflow ([Can I add a reference to a .NET Framework DLL from a .NET 6 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005465/can-i-add-a-reference-to-a-net-framework-dll-from-a-net-6-project)) and reading the .Net compatibility, it seems not to be possible.

So is it possible or not?

To be honest, the huge amount of different .NET flavors and the continuous renaming makes it really hard to see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Please edit to be specific (also, you can remove comments like "some posts at Stack Overflow" - there's no possible way to know what posts you're referring to, and it doesn't really add to your question). As written, it's unclear what your specific question is. Further, this really seems like more of a rant, as written. And this really isn't the place for rants.

Answer (score 5):

There is a compatibility mode in .NET 5+ and .NET Core 3.1 that should allow you to do what you want. Check it out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#net-framework-compatibility-mode)!