# 'as' casting returns null in .net6

Tags: c#, casting, frameworks, .net-6.0

So we have this class `FilePickerDialog` derived from `CustomDialog` class.
`FilePickerDialog` is built with .net framework while `CustomDialog` is built with .net6

Then we have an application in .net6 that instantiate `objFilePickerDialog` and later on casted to `CustomDialog` using `objFilePickerDialog as CustomDialog`, this resulted as a null.

Once we rebuilt `FilePickerDialog` into .net6, then the casting works. However, we are not sure what is the explanation to this situation. Can someone help to clear the air for us?

Comment: Wait...you're saying that you're referencing a .NET 6 library from .NET Framework?

Comment: Nope, the other way round. I have an migrated .NET 6 application that still reference some .NET Framework libraries.
Just noticed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005465/can-i-add-a-reference-to-a-net-framework-dll-from-a-net-6-project). I guess it is not recommended to do it this way, it should be .NET 6 throughout the entire application. Some .net framework libraries might still work in .net 6 application but not guaranteed.