# Use .NET 6 class library in >NET 4.7 ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, portable-class-library

Is that possible that a class library which is created in >NET 6 can be used as reference in ASP.NET Website created in .NET 4.7 framework

I didn't try any thing yet

Comment: **Only** if that class library is targetting **.NET Standard 2.0** - otherwise **no**, you can't do that

Comment: `I didn't try any thing yet` Please do not ask questions without have tried anything. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

If you can build the `.NET 6` package as `.NET Standard` library then yes. Otherwise **not**.

For example a `.NET Standard 2.0` library can be used in:

.NET Framework  `4.6.1`, `4.6.2`, `4.7`, `4.7.1`, `4.7.2`, `4.8`, `4.8.1`

- [.NET Standard Documentation (MS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0#select-net-standard-version)
- [What is the difference between .NET versions (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005465/can-i-add-a-reference-to-a-net-framework-dll-from-a-net-6-project)
- [Referencing DLLs from .NET 6 (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005465/can-i-add-a-reference-to-a-net-framework-dll-from-a-net-6-project)

Comment: And it **has to be** .NET Standard **2.0** - not 2.1 - to support the "old" .NET framework ..