# Couldn't load File or assembly 'System.Runtime.dll, Version=6.0.0.0'

Tags: wix, .net-6.0, .net-4.8, .net-standard-2.0

Actually in my Application .net Framework and .net standard was there which is working Fine And the bootstrapper packages are installing fine.

due to some reason we have migrated one of the project to .net 6, then I was able to build , but during installation of the packages i am getting the error

```
Couldn't Load the assembly 'System.Runtime.dll version=6.0.0.0' 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

during debugging I found that the exception raise in one of the .net standard calss the code where the error is occurring is

```
cobj = Activator.CreateInstance(<classType>,
                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                            null, args, null);
```

and the actual line of the class constructor  where it fails to create a object is

```
/config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(GetType().Assembly.Location);
```

ConfigurationManager is present under namespace `System.Configuration`;

I feel since earlier .net standard and .net framework were there this piece of code was working ,but one of the component is in .net 6 so this line giving exception .

is there any alter solution is there .

Comment: Is the .NET 6 project used by any of .NET Framework ones (directly or transitively)?

Comment: yes the .net 6 has a reference project which is a .net framework 4.8 class library

Comment: actually earlier i thought may be because of the framework library this issue is coming during installation ,so i have migrate that to .net standard library but still the issue has not resolve

Comment: Migrate that lib to .NET Standard - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70005465/2501279)

Comment: HI @GuruStron I have migrate that library to .net standard 2.0 build is getting pass but still during installation this paricular line gives error ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(GetType().Assembly.Location); and gives unable to load error in windows event viewer .

Comment: Hi @GuruStron actually for setup I am using wix project there I haven't mention anything for installing .net 6 , i thought since in my local pc .net 6 is there it can work, is it wrong ?

Comment: Based on docs [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) seems to be not a part of the .NET Standard/.NET.

Comment: Hi @GuruStron , then can I write something else other then ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration that can support .net framework assemblies also .

Comment: You need conditional compilation for that.

Comment: I have put if (RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription.StartsWith(".NET Framework")) for validating .net framework assembly but still the error is coming while installing the package in event viewer in visual studio debugging i couldn't reproduce the same error

Comment: hi @GuruStron can you please suggest what is the correct alternate for ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration in .net standard 2.0

Comment: hi @GuruStron actually they have taken wix toolset for creating Setup flle, but after I migrate one of its component into .net 6 i have done any changes to the wix projects does that cause any issue because file tag inside component tag we have to remove assembly manifest ,because .net 6 doesn't support that