# .NET 8 project that uses .NET framework 4.5 project

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution where the startup project is written using .NET 8 (API).
Due to legacy reasons I have to use an old project, as a helper, that is in .NET framework 4.5 (class library).

While I attempt to access a property from from the .NET framework project, I get:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Any ideas of what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, you can give [.NET Framework compatibility mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#net-framework-compatibility-mode) a try, but chances are it might not work, you can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77947016/21096898).