# Why the nuget dll shows in project root in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, clr

I have an SDK project in my solution. And i need to add a NuGet package ("customLib.net"), which provides the functionality to find the differences between files.

If you create a simple ***.Net Framework 4.7.2*** console application and add this NuGet to it, then it will automatically download it along with all dependencies, including "customLib.redist.windows.x64". As i understand "customLib.net.dll" is an API for .net, and "customLib.dll" *(which comes from "customLib.redist.windows.x64" package)* is an engine itself, compiled for *win-x64*. The package is stored in *SolutionFolder/packages*. And there is a *package.config* file with all required references. And everything works as expected.

But if to add the same NuGet package to SDK (Class Library) project, which has the same target: ***.Net Framework 4.7.2***, it should also download the NuGet package along with all dependencies. And it does. But it doesn't store the packages in *SolutionFolder/packages* folder, and there are no any *package.config* files. It stores them in global NuGet storage on C drive. And the **problem** is that when i launch the application it **throws an exception in runtime**:

```
"Unable to load DLL 'customLib': The specified module could not be found.".
```

And this dll doesn't exists in output folder. I solved this issue by downloading the *"customLib.redist.windows.x64"* NuGet package to the project, despite the fact that *"customLib.net"* already has a reference to this package. This is a little bit weird for me, **and here are the questions:**

1. Why, if a *"customLib.net"* depends on *"customLib.redist.windows.x64"*, it does not copy dependent dll to the output folder? At the same time, the console application copies both libraries.
2. Why after downloading *"customLib.redist.windows.x64"* NuGet the *"customLib.dll"* file  shows in my project root in Visual Studio with full path to "C:\Users\MyUsr\.nuget\packages\customLib.redist.windows.x64\1.0.1\runtimes\win-x64"?

Answer (score 0):

As per the description, I can assume that you have .NET standard console application but you added the .Net core class library into it. That's why you are facing such issues.

Because in the .NET core library project, there is no package.config file and references were added directly to the csproj file. As well as packages downloaded to the user's directory, instead of the packages folder.

So, instead of adding a .Net core library, you need to add the .NET standard class library into your project

To know more about it refer to [What is the difference between .NET Core and .NET Standard Class Library project types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42939454/5755994)

Comment: No. There are no any issues with console application, which has the target: .Net Framework 4.7.2. It works as expected. There is a problem with my SDK project, which is class library for .Net Framework 4.7.2