# How to reference .Net 6.0 project from WinUI 3 project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class-library, visual-studio-project

I have a .NET 6.0 C# class library project that contains platform-independent code (let's call this `BusinessLogic`). In my same solution, I would like to create a project for a WinUI 3 app that references this class library (let's call this `WindowsApp`). I would also like to create a class library specific to the Windows platform (so I can access the `Windows.Storage` namespace from within that class library, for example... let's call this `WindowsOS`).

I get an error when attempting to set this up. I have tried two techniques:

First technique

1. Create a .NET 6.0 C# class library `WindowsOS`.
2. In `WindowsOS` project, add reference to `BusinessLogic`. No problem.
3. In `WindowsOS` project, install NuGet packages `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools` and `Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK`. This gives me an error about numeric comparisons on the target platform, similar to the one described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/361). Afterwards, the project becomes unloadable in Visual Studio.

Second technique

1. Create a Class Library (Universal Windows) project `WindowsOS`.
2. In `WindowsOS` project, add reference to `BusinessLogic`. This gives me an error immediately, simply refusing to allow the reference to be added.

I suspect there appears to be some compatibility issue going on. I reviewed the [Microsoft docs on .NET Standard versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077&tabs=net-standard-2-1), as well as [this helpful StackOverflow question about .NET Core vs .NET Standard class libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939454/what-is-the-difference-between-net-core-and-net-standard-class-library-project), and from what I can tell UWP may not be capable of referencing .NET class libraries.

My end goal is to create a WinUI 3 desktop app that references these cross-platform class libraries. My common code is contained in these libraries, and I may make an Android app or other platform app in a separate project that also references these same cross-platform class libraries. How do I do this?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the error from technique #1:

[image]

Comment: It wants to parse the SDK version number.  So use as indicated in the github issue (say) "net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0"

Comment: @HansPassant you are correct on how to fix the warning! I explain how to do this in my answer - but investigating the project properties XML (.csproj) I did see that changing the properties as described in my answer does indeed adjust this value as you describe! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. In the Visual Studio project properties (screenshot below), there is a `Target OS` property. That property defaults to `(None)`.

Given the names of the projects in the question, set the property accordingly:

1. Set the property value to `Windows` in the `WindowsOS` project. This will give access to Windows-platform specific namespaces (such as `Windows.Storage`). `WindowsOS` can still have a project reference to `BusinessLogic` (and any .NET 6.0 C# library) as before.
2. No change necessary to the `BusinessLogic` project properties.
3. The `WindowsApp` (WinUI 3) project also requires no changes, and can reference BOTH the `WindowsOS` project (which now has a `Target OS` of `Windows`) AND the `BusinessLogic` project (which still has a `Target OS` property of `(None)`.

Something to keep in mind: the `WindowsApp` project and the `WindowsOS` project will now both have `Target OS version` and `Supported OS version` properties. If you set these to different values in each project, you will get compiler warnings about a potential conflict (a user could install the app with a lower version of Windows, but that app then references the library which may require a higher version of Windows than the user has, for example). This does not matter if you are only using APIs supported in BOTH versions of Windows, but to be safe make sure these are consistent between your projects.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio project properties page]