# Challenges Running a .NET Standard 2.0 Test App on Linux and macOS

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm currently working on creating a test application using .NET Standard 2.0 as the target framework. In my current project, my .csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I have successfully built and executed the TestAPP.dll on a Windows machine, and it produced the expected output. However, when I attempted the same process on a Linux or macOS system, I encountered difficulties running the TestAPP.dll. It's important to note that netstandard2.0 is not intended to be a runnable target framework. Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the steps to run a .NET Standard 2.0 project on Windows:

1. Open a command prompt or terminal.
2. Navigate to your project's directory.
3. Create a new console application using the following command:

> dotnet new console

4   Open the .csproj file of your project in a text editor or an Integrated Development Environment (IDE).

5   In the .csproj file, locate the  element and change it to netstandard2.0. Save the changes.

6   Build your project using the following command:

```
dotnet build
```

7   If you encounter any errors related to the C# language version, use the following command to specify the language version (e.g., C# 10.0):

```
dotnet build /p:LangVersion=10.0
```

8   After a successful build, navigate to the output directory. Depending on your build configuration, it will be one of the following paths:

> bin\Debug\netstandard2.0

9   To run your application, directly call the application's DLL file (e.g., TestAPP.dll) from the command prompt using the dotnet command. Replace "TestAPP.dll" with the actual name of your application's DLL:
TestAPP.dll
This will execute your .NET Standard 2.0 application from the command line.

Comment: What did you try and what what did you expect and what happened instead? What version of .net are you using?

Comment: "It's important to note that netstandard2.0 is not intended to be a runnable target framework" - indeed, so why have you used it for an executable project?

Comment: I developed a "Hello World" example using .NET Standard 2.0 and attempted to execute the output, which in my case is TestAPP.dll. I successfully obtained the "Hello World" result in Windows.

Comment: Do you understand what needs to go in the `<TargetFramework>` element? Do you know about the differences between [.Net, .Net Framework, and .Net Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939454/what-is-the-difference-between-net-core-and-net-standard-class-library-project)?

Comment: My inquisitive query revolves around the "how" and "why" of running a .NET Standard 2.0 application successfully on Windows but encountering issues when attempting to run it on Linux or macOS.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I hit my head against the wall!" Well then stop trying to make _an executable_ targeting .Net Standard.

Comment: @Jess33 I think you would have to tell us how you managed to run it on windows because I'm not aware of a way to run netstandard on windows without "driving" it somehow

Comment: @JoePhillips I have updated the question with the steps to run a .NET Standard 2.0 project on Windows.

Comment: `However, when I attempted the same process on a Linux or macOS system, I encountered difficulties running the TestAPP.dll` how about you tell us **what those difficulties were** instead of assuming we can see your terminal?

Comment: @IanKemp The error message appears to indicate a fatal issue: The 'libhostpolicy.so' library, necessary for running the application, was not located in the '/TestNew/Test/TestApp/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/' directory. Consequently, the application failed to execute as a self-contained app